# mandatory security group

Tags: security

trying to solve a permission issue.  We have created a custom permission level called Site Owner that removes the ability to create subsites but keeps everything else, including the ability to edit permissions.

This has caused problems with site owners removing their own permissions.  We are trying to solve the issue of providing access for a technical support team that cannot be removed but without making the support team Site Collection Admins or higher.

does anyone know of a way to give permissions to a particular security group and remove the ability to delete that group's permissions, even if the site owner has edit permission ability?

Comment: Hi Zane, for the purposes of helping the rest of the SharePoint community - what was your final solution? If you could add it as an answer and Mark it as such, that would help all.

Answer (score 1):

Failing writing your own authorisation logic or permissions manager to replace that of SharePoint, I'd say you are only left with the option of making those who need to always retain permission site collection administrators.